# Numpy array division in list comprehension causes massive RAM bloat?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, memory-leaks, list-comprehension

I've just encountered an issue with division in list comprehension and I'm not sure how to work around it, and I'm also curious why this happens.

I have a folder of 30 images, totalling 300MB (about 12MB each)

The following code is fine and loads the images without issue:

```py
import cv2

image_ids = [...] # contains the image names
images = [cv2.imread('data/' + id) for id in image_ids]
```

This consumes about 0.5GB of ram which is still quite a bit of overhead but reasonable.
But then I tried out this code:

```py
import cv2

image_ids = [...] # contains the image names
images = [cv2.imread('data/' + id) / 255.0 for id in image_ids]
```

This simple modification caused the RAM to spike from 1GB RAM by Python to 5GB RAM.
How can I do this in a way that won't cause so much garbage in the memory, and why does it happen?

I also tried to use `gc.collect()` after the fact but it didn't clear any memory.

Comment: The first one should store the images as `np.uint8`, the second one as `np.float32`, thus at least four times the memory. So, kind of expected behaviour!?

Comment: True that, but even then, if we consider it's 300MB of images, it should be at most 1.2GB, possibly up to 2GB with some overhead. Problem is it spikes up to 5GB instead

Comment: Do you take into account, that images are stored "raw" (every pixel stores 3 bytes for color images) during runtime? Do you have 12 MB JPG images, 12 MB PNG images (compression?), 12 MB TIFF images? What are the images' dimensions? You can simply calculate the theoretical amount of memory needed from the image dimensions.

Comment: I have indeed. They are 12 MB PNG 8-bit images. Meaning the 12 MB encompass an entire image, which should mean that when converted to float32 they should take 48 MB total, so a total of 1440MB for all images, approximately, not the unexpected 4-5GB. I don't perform any other operations upon the images

Comment: Again, what are your images' dimensions? 12 MB PNG saved to disk doesn't mean 12 MB unpacked in memory. Even if your PNGs are lossless, compression like zlib can still be applied without altering the image itself, but it's file size.

Comment: 3406x3406x1 is each image, so it about matches 12MB each. I verified they are 8-bit single channel

Comment: Ah, geez! The default is `np.float64`, not `np.float32` when using the above command! So, you have factor 8 between both versions. I ran some tests using `images = [np.random.randint(0, 256, (3406, 3406), np.uint8) / 255.0 for i in range(30)]`, and I get around 2.7 GB of memory usage (only related to the image storing), which is close to the calculated value. Still not 5 GB, yes, but reasonable nevertheless.

Comment: @HansHirse Also in the example code, OP uses `imread` with default flags, i.e. with `IMREAD_COLOR`. So the grayscale images from disk are loaded as BGR, if I"m not mistaken, so another times 3 right there...

Comment: @DanMašek Ah, thanks for pointing that out, you're absolutely right! Using the actual `cv2.imread` call with a fitting grayscale image, I get 8 GB of memory usage solely for the image storing. So, in conclusion, everything's as expected.

Comment: It's all starting to make more sense now, thanks all for the information that I didn't see in plain sight, a lot of contributors